# Get meeting link with Google calendar api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm looking to use the Google calendar API for an application, but I'd like to get a Google meet link (for a G Suite account). As far as I can see that option is not possible, or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am searching for same, have you found any way to get meeting link?

Answer (score 3):

As per https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/hangouts-meet-now-available-in-google

You need to search for element with `entryPointType = "video"` in ConferenceData.entryPoints[] and then you can use matchedObject.uri to get the Google meet link.

In Javascript / nodejs the solution will be something similar to:

```js
var {google} = require('googleapis');

const eventId = "<yourEventId>";
const calendarId = "<yourCalendarId>";

const calendar = google.calendar({
    version : "v3",
    auth : auth
});

calendar.events.get({
    calendarId,
    eventId
}, ( err, res ) => {
    if( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    } else {
        const conferenceData = res.conferenceData;
        if( conferenceData ) {
            const entryPoints = conferenceData.entryPoints;
            if( entryPoints ) {
                const videoDetails = entryPoints.find( entryPoint => entryPoint.entryPointType == "video" );
                if( videoDetails ) {
                    console.log( "Google Meet link", videoDetails.uri );
                } else {
                    console.log( "No video details available" );
                }
            } else {
                console.log( "No entry points available" );
            }
        } else {
            console.log( "No conference data available" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's only [hangoutLink](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) in calendar API. If you'd like to know how to use it in Javascript, check [this guide](https://medium.com/@JoeSalowitz/how-to-add-google-calendar-hangouts-links-to-mac-and-ios-calendar-events-af365cd93a3c).

Comment: Thanks! I had seen it. But it only gives you a hangouts link, I was interested in a Google meet link. Is that not available?