# how to create hangout meeting using Google Calendaer API?

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

**This is from google API documentation**
** it work good but I steel need auto create hangout meeting**

```
`$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'GooGlE API',
    'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
    'start' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2020-06-02T09:00:00-07:00',
      'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',

    ),
    'end' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2020-06-02T09:00:00-07:00',
      'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
    'recurrence' => array(
      'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
    ),
    'attendees' => array(

    //   array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
    ),
    'reminders' => array(
      'useDefault' => FALSE,
      'overrides' => array(
        array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
        array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
      ),
    ),
));

  $calendarId = 'primary';
  $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
  printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);`
```

**how to create hangout meeting using Google Calendar API ?**

Comment: Using [conferenceData](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#conferencing) as mentioned in the docs can add or create a meet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get meeting link with Google calendar api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738713/get-meeting-link-with-google-calendar-api)